# Assistance requested with a small VBScript project

Tags: sql, ms-access, vbscript, adodb

I got an accdb file from a friend which has info for spells she's making for a tabletop RPG (on the idea of D&D). One of the columns on this table is called "Type" and within it are multiple entries such as Dark, Poison, Healing etc.

My objectives for this project are as follows:

- Get the unique entries in the Types column
- Count the number of times each type is repeated in the Types Column
- Display the data in a message box like this:

  ```
  Dark = n
  Poison = n
  Healing = n
  ```

Where `n =` is the number of times that type is repeated in the Types column.

Here is the code I have so far:

```vb
Dim connStr, objConn, getTypes

connStr = "Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source = Rachelle_TableTop_RPG_Spells_0.1.1.accdb"

Set objConn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")

objConn.Open connStr

Set rs = objConn.Execute("SELECT Distinct(Type) FROM Spells")

Do While Not rs.EOF
  getTypes = getTypes + rs.Fields(0) & " = " & vbCrLf
  rs.MoveNext
Loop

objConn.Close
Set rs = Nothing
Set objConn = Nothing

MsgBox getTypes
```

It displays a message box that appears as my goal above except without a number.

I would like assistance figuring out what queries etc I should use to reach my objectives. I am not looking for someone to rewrite my code for me.

Comment: Not sure where to begin to be honest, the question is a bit too broad in scope to be on topic. Will say one thing, the loop is completely unnecessary. Instead use something like `SELECT Type, COUNT(Type) FROM Spells GROUP BY Type` would be a better approach.

Comment: @Lankymart Agree on the query, but he still needs a loop for building the desired output.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Yeah, wasn’t clear as I was writing it. What I meant was they don't need to loop through the recordset as `GetRows()` would do. But you’ll still need a loop of some description to output the resultant array.

Comment: Why bother with extra step of populating array? Trying this code but cannot get connection to work.

Comment: @June7 because that way we don't have to maintain the database connection, personal preference but recordsets are bloaty things. When you just want the data and nothing else an array is far more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Connection string needs full file path to the database if script not in same folder as database. To get the connection to work I had to follow advice in: https://rtmccormick.com/2014/06/05/provider-cannot-be-found-it-may-not-be-properly-installed/

I created a shortcut and set the Target with:
`%windir%\SysWoW64\wscript.exe C:\filepath\filename.vbs`

Read elsewhere to:
"edit cmd file to run the 32-bit process
windir%\SysWoW64\cmd.exe /c C:\filepath\filename.vbs
instead of just
C:\filepath\filename.vbs"
Did not follow up on that.

Change the query for the recordset:

`SELECT [Type], COUNT([Type]) AS CountType FROM Spells GROUP BY [Type]`

Type has special meaning in Access. Using reserved words as names might cause issue. Enclose fieldname in [ ] or don't use reserved words as names for anything.

Concatenation within loop to build string:

`getTypes = getTypes & rs.Fields(0) & " is repeated " & rs.Fields(1) & " times" & vbCrLf`

Comment: I haven't needed to use the full path for the database since I put the script file in the same folder, just the filename.

Using [] Doesn't do anything different from not using them

The code for `getTypes` you offered does work, except it only comes up with one entry. Do I need to use a loop to get the others? Or is there something else I can use?

Comment: I did say 'might' cause issue. For instance, Date is a function and therefore a reserved word. If you name a field Date then reference in query without [ ], bad things can happen. Yes, of course still need the loop. I did not even suggest removing loop.

Comment: Nice reguration of the original comments, not sure you've really answered the question mind. Also, just to be clear `Type` isn't a [Access Database Engine reserved word](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/learn-about-access-reserved-words-and-symbols-ae9d9ada-3255-4b12-91a9-f855bdd9c5a2#__toc262648755).

Comment: It's on Allen Browne's list as a field property. True, probably not an issue in this situation.

Comment: The query code and the code for `getTypes` that June7 posted did what I needed. Thank you